# Test Meteor packages from forked Git repo

Tags: github, meteor, nitrousio, meteor-autoform

I'm using Nitrous.io and cannot directly access package files on my dev server there (not sure if that's specific to them or all Meteor projects).

I'm also using Autoform. I needed to change something in a file in the Autoform package. Since I couldn't access it directly, I created a fork of Autoform and made the changes there.

But... I'm new and clueless as to how I can test this change on my dev server.

Comment: Create a packages directory in your meteor project and then "git clone" your fork into it.  When you "meteor add" the package, meteor will find it in your packages directory.

Comment: @MarkLeiber that should be an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a packages directory in your meteor project and then "git clone" your fork into it. When you "meteor add" the package, meteor will find it in your packages directory.